# org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException:

Tags: java, database, hibernate, c3p0

I got this exception with this code:

```
public void saveOrUpdateBs(ArrayList<B> list) throws DBConnectionException{
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    s.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
    s.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
    Transaction transaction = s.beginTransaction();
    for(B sub:list){
        s.saveOrUpdate(sub);
    }
    transaction.commit();
    s.flush();
    s.clear();
}
```

AT THE commit step. The following is my hibernate.cfg.xml setting:

```
org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: could not insert: [com.B]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:124)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2454)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2874)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at com.Bdao.saveOrUpdateBs(Bdao.java:197)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment SST.SYS_LOB0000152519C00009$$ by 1024 in tablespace SST

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10700)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2434)
... 16 more
```

Is there anything I set wrong in the hibernate.cfg.xml about timeout?
Could anyone please give me some hint.

Comment: Did you think to google what that Oracle error means? http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/oracle/ORA01691.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate timeout is a red herring.

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment SST.SYS_LOB0000152519C00009$$ by 1024 in tablespace SST
```

Your database's datafile is full.  You need to ask your DBA to add more capacity to your tablespace.